# How do I install the telnet module (.tar.gz file) in Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

I downloaded Strawberry Perl and also downloaded a standalone `Net::Telnet` module as FTP is blocked by a firewall.

The Telnet module is a `.tar.gz` file. How should I install it in Windows XP?

Comment: http://p3rl.org/modinstall

Answer (score 2):

Short term solution:

Untar it, `perl Makefile.PL` and `make test install`.

On Strawberry Perl you should have `ptar` if you lack `tar`, and `nmake` if you lack `make`.

If `perl Makefile.PL` returns missing prerequisites, be sure to install those first (same way: download module, untar it, etc).

Long term solution:

- Use [CPAN::Mini](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Mini/lib/CPAN/Mini.pm) in a place with FTP/HTTP access to mirror CPAN to a USB stick or shared directory
- Instruct CPAN to use the location of the mounted USB stick/shared directory to use as source for CPAN modules (see the [CPAN::Mini](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Mini/lib/CPAN/Mini.pm) docs for how to do this)
- Keep your "minicpan" up to date regularly, and
- Use cpan/cpanm/cpanplus to install modules

Answer (score 1):

The **Padre on Strawberry Perl** distribution now includes Net::Telnet as well.
http://padre.perlide.org/download.html but the more generic solution is what @mfontani wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ptar zxf Net-Telnet-3.03.tar.gz
cd Net-Telnet-3.03
perl Makefile.PL
dmake
dmake test
dmake install
```

Comment: I'm getting errors while trying this at the `dmake` step. Details are in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086296)